# Uniqueness of solution of Cauchy-Euler ODE, with conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Suppose we have two "similar" non-homogeneous ODE:
>
> 1. $x^2y''-6y=12$
> 2. $x^2y''+2xy'-6y=12$
>
> Find a solution that satisfies $y(1)=3$.

I solved the equations as usual and got that the solution families are:

1. ${y(x) = -2 +\frac{c_1}{x^{2}} + c_2x^{3} }$
2. ${y(x) = -2 +\frac{c_1}{x^{3}} + c_2x^{2} }$

Now my question is, how do I determine that the solution that satisfies $y(1)=3$ is unique AND is defined for each ${x \in \mathbb{R} }$?

I checked the Wronskian for both cases and it turned out that the first case has $W=5$ and the seconds has $W=\frac{5}{x^{2}}$,  what does it necessarily mean that the Wronskian is not defined at one point? ($x=0$)

Comment: "the solution that satisfies y(1)=3 is unique" Why do you think it is? By your own work, it is not. "AND is defined for each x∈R" Why do you think it is? Note that this is definitely not what you are asked to show.

Comment: @Did The real question asks you to find a solution that satisfies $y(1)=3$ and is defined for each ${x \in \mathbb{R} }$  and to determine whether it is unique or not

Comment: Yeah, the "real question" is not what you wrote in your post. Re the "real question", I fail to understand the problem since you already know all the solutions. Surely you can check that, in both cases, exactly one of these is defined on the whole real line **and** fits the condition y(1)=3?

Comment: @Did Well the real question is written in my own words at the last sentence but you thought I was making it up :| 
I am just wondering whether it is correct to choose $c1=0$ to get rid of the problematic side of not being defined at $x=0$?, Nicely asking :)

Comment: @alexander_yz Again, you have written yourself everything you need... Look at case 1. Which solutions are defined on the whole real line? Which ones are not? Among those defined on the whole real line, what are/is those/the one such that y(1)=3? Ergo?

Comment: @Did I just don't understand something, both solution families indicate that there's something problematic at $x=0$ but I think that choosing a constant ($c1=0$) can give us a unique solution that is defined for each x, correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @alexander_yz Yes, some solutions are not defined at 0, the others are defined everywhere (several of them). Amongst those defined everywhere, one and exactly one is such that y(1)=3. QED.

Comment: @Did by the way I checked the wronskian for both cases and it turned out that the first case has $W=5$ and the seconds has $W=\frac{5}{x^{2}}$,  what does it necessarily mean that the wronskian is not defined at one point :o

Comment: If you have a new question, ask it in another post (or add it to the present one, since it received no answer, so far).

Comment: @Did If I edited the original question will you be able to answer :3

Comment: Since your new questions are rather unclear at the moment, I could not tell you this before you will have edited your post. (And why does it matter if I answer you, or other users?)

Comment: @Did Well it doesn't matter who answers, I just think that this "discovery" could tell something about the uniqueness of the solution.

Comment: At this point, and in view of your edit which sems to repeat some previous misconceptions, I am not sure: do you understand that the question "Find a solution that satisfies y(1)=3 and is defined for each x∈ℝ and determine whether it is unique or not" is fully answered?

Comment: Again, @alexander_yz? Sorry but **the question is solved**. (BenW: See the effects of the noise I was alluding to earlier?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the extended banter.  So anyway, here is the correct answer, summarized.

The theorem that you want to use is the following (it can be found in pretty much every undergraduate DiffEq textbook):  Let $I$ be an open interval, and let $p,q,f$ be continuous functions on $I$.  Consider the equations:
\begin{equation}\tag{NH}y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=f(x)\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\tag{H}y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0\end{equation}
Suppose $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly independent solutions to (H) on $I$, and $y_p$ is any solution to (NH) on $I$.  Then every solution to (NH) on $I$ has the form
$$y(x)=y_p(x)+c_1y_1(x)+c_2y_2(x)$$
where $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now, rewrite your equation (2) as
$$y''+2x^{-1}y'-6x^{-2}y=12x^{-2}$$
Note that this is (NH) with $p(x)=2x^{-1}$, $q(x)=-6x^{-2}$, and $f(x)=12x^{-2}$, all continuous on $(0,\infty)$.  Note that $y_1(x)=x^{-3}$ and $y_2(x)=x^2$ are LI solutions to (H) in this case, and that $y_p(x)=-2$ is a solution to (NH).  Hence, every solution to (NH) on $(0,\infty)$ has the form
$$y_+(x)=-2+c_1x^{-3}+c_2x^2.$$
I'm calling it $y_+$ instead of just $y$ because this is only true for solutions defined on $(0,\infty)$.  Similarly, every solution to (NH) on $(-\infty,0)$ has the form
$$y_-(x)=-2+d_1x^{-3}+d_2x^2.$$
If $y$ is a solution on $\mathbb{R}$, then $y$ must agree with $y_-$ and $y_+$ on their domains. Note that $c_1=d_1=0$, since  otherwise we would have $\lim_{x\to 0}y(x)$ either infinite or nonexistent, violating differentiability of $y$.  Thus, $y(x)=-2+c_1x^2$ on $(0,\infty)$ and $=-2+d_1x^2$ on $(-\infty,0)$.  Since we require $y(1)=3$, this means $c_1=5$.  Note that $y'(x)=10x$ if $x>0$ and $y'(x)=2d_1x$ if $x<0$. Since $y''$ exists, this means $d_1=5$ as well. For continuity we must include $y(0)=-2$ and now we get
$$y(x)=-2+5x^2$$
as the unique solution to (2) on $\mathbb{R}$ with $y(1)=3$.

Case (1) is similar, but with one crucial difference. Similar to (2), we find that
$$y(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}-2+d_2x^3,&x<0\\-2+5x^3&x\geq 0\end{array}\right.$$
But now $d_2$ can be any value at all, because we get
$$y'(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}3d_2x^2,&x<0\\15x^2&x\geq 0\end{array}\right.$$
and hence
$$y''(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}6d_2x,&x<0\\30x&x\geq 0\end{array}\right.$$
so that (1) is satisfied on $\mathbb{R}$ with $y(1)=3$.

However, note that if we require that $y$ be three times differentiable then $d_2=5$ so the solution is unique in that special case.

Comment: @BenW Thank you so much for the thoroughly analysed answer, I can clearly understand the answer and the differences right now!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net but we have two different situations